# Extracting audio track to determine the song beat

Tags: audio, signal-analysis

I'm completely new to this field.

Perhaps I'm calling it by a wrong name, but I want to analyze an audio track and retrieve a **timestamp to beat** mapping.

Is there an open source 3rd party library that can perform this, or could/should I do it myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Sonic Annotator](http://www.omras2.org/SonicAnnotator). Good: their beat tracking algorithm is the most sophisticated. Bad: this is not easy to integrate and interface into your own application (you need to load their own flavor of plug-ins called "VAMP"); and the beat tracker is closed source - available as a pre-compiled binary lib.

[Aubio](http://aubio.org/). Good: very easy to integrate, plain C with few dependencies. Bad: the quality of the beat-tracking is so-so.

[Marsyas](http://marsyas.info/). Good: beat-tracking accuracy is OK (but not as good as Sonic Annotator's). Bad: many dependencies, very complex framework.

Depending on what is your target application (is the audio to analyze a recording of a well-known/distributed song, and does your system have internet access), you could also use the [Echo Nest APIs](http://developer.echonest.com/docs/v4/track.html#analyze).

If you want to roll your own, I suggest you [this](http://labrosa.ee.columbia.edu/projects/beattrack/) as a starting point - start porting this rather simple matlab implementation to your language of choice, and you'll be at 80% or 90% of the accuracy of the most sophisticated solution.

Comment: Thanks, but this seem like a very big overhead for a POC application... I would have to consider something else for the time... I would get back to this later on... Thanks again.

Comment: Great answer, I'm in fact working on a causal beat-tracker that works similarly to the one in Marsyas but is very much simplified(something like 400 lines of python total, no dependencies other than numpy/scipy). But just wanted to say that you missed one: http://code.soundsoftware.ac.uk/projects/beatroot it was actually the winner at the 2006 MIREX thing which most later beat tracking projects use samples from to measure their performance. It's in java and it has a GUI for showing the beat positions with the sound wave and can provide a good starting point

Comment: The main issue I've encountered implementing this, which caused me to drop this at least for the near future is the fact that I needed this to work on Android... and building and exporting any of these libraries, just seemed too much.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try [Essentia](http://essentia.upf.edu/). It provides [several beat tracker methods](http://essentia.upf.edu/documentation/reference/std_RhythmExtractor2013.html), which are more-or-less state of the art. Technically portable to android also, although it has not been done yet.